# Enum changes not visible in Enterprise Portal

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, aot

I have added a couple of items and modified the labels of items held in a `Base Enum` and these changes do not appear immediately on the Enterprise Portal web page in which they are used (currently the enums are used in combo boxes).

I did some changes yesterday, and these changes were then visible in EP this morning (I can't explain why) but the ones I just did, not visible.

I tried compiling the form, redeploying the Page Definition, sync. the data dictionary, no go.

How can I make the changes visible at will, as soon as I am done with them ?

Thanks!

EDIT: Seems like doing an IISRESET on the EP machine did the trick. So I guess restarting the application pool of the EP website should have done the trick as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iisreset is fine (EP uses mostly the datasets, and that need only iisreset).

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you done a Refresh AOD?

Looking at [Using AX Labels in EP 2009](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/epblog/archive/2008/07/01/using-ax-labels-in-ep-2009.aspx), it states:

> As a final note I would like to mention that [Enterprise Portal] will cache all labels for all languages in memory on the web server to improve performance. You can clear this cache by doing a Refresh AOD.

According to other sources, AX automatically clears it's cache at midnight every day. This would certainly explain why changes you made yesterday would be visible, while current changes are not.

Comment: Tried that, no go. The only thing that does it on the spot is a restart of the IIS application pool running EP.

Comment: An IIS reset makes sense, if it's a caching issue. I know that it isn't exactly recommended if the site is being used heavily. Seems odd there wouldn't be another way of forcing a cache reset on specific elements though. Unfortunately, I have no experience with EP so there isn't much I can add.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the AOD and Data dictionary should reflect your changes.

Please check for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc554278.aspx